# Rundeck permission denied issue while executing a job in remote host machine

Tags: permissions, rundeck

Earlier I have installed Rundeck in local machine and Everything was working fine for me . Recently I have installed rundeck in remote host machine where ssh and sudo user are different for this machine and they are not in same group .
When I am trying to run the job(python scripts) , it is throwing me below permisision denied message . Do I need to change the user level details somewhere in a file, Please let me know .

/bin/sh: /tmp/4-10-host-machine-dispatch-script.tmp.sh: Permission denied
Result: 126
Failed: NonZeroResultCode: Result code was 126

Thanks,
RK

Answer (score 2):

That means the `/tmp` directory is restricted in your remote node (some servers setups restrict that by security reasons), you can define a custom copy script path in multiples ways:

1) *Node level:* defining `file-copy-destination-dir` attribute at `resoruces.xml` file, example:

```xml
<node name="freebsd11" description="FreeBSD 11 node" tags="unix,freebsd" hostname="192.168.33.41" osArch="amd64" osFamily="unix" osName="FreeBSD" osVersion="11.3-RELEASE" username="youruser" ssh-key-storage-path="keys/rundeck" file-copy-destination-dir="/home/youruser/scripts"/>
```

2) *Project level:* Go to Edit Configuration (Rundeck sidebar) > Edit Configuration > Edit Configuration File (up to right button) and add this line:

```
project.file-copy-destination-dir=/home/youruser/scripts
```

3) *Globally:* Stop Rundeck service, add the following line at `project.properties` (at `/etc/rundeck` path) file and start Rundeck service again:

```
framework.file-copy-destination-dir=/home/youruser/script
```

Just make sure that the custom path is reachable by the remote ssh user. You can check the full documentation [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/projects/node-execution/builtin.html#file-copier-destination-directory).

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable comments